# Submitting a PHP form from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an HTML file, JavaScript file and a PHP file. The JavaScript is used to validate the user input and then to pass the form into the PHP page.

The validation function is working great, but the form will not submit from the JavaScript to the PHP file.

After spending two days on this, I still can not figure out what I have wrong and why the JavaScript will not submit the form data into the PHP file and how to get the PHP page to appear after submitting

HTML:

```
<div class = "formtext">
<p>
<form id = "formtext" name="survey" method="post" action="formtext.php">
<table id="surveytable" width="300" border="1">
<tr>
<td>
    Name: 
        <input type = "text" id="userName" 
name="name" onkeyup="document.getElementById('mirror').innerHTML=this.value" />
    <br/ >
    Your name: <span id="mirror"></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    Number: 
        <input type = "text" id="userNumber" 
name="number" onkeyup="document.getElementById('mirror1').innerHTML=this.value" />
    <br />
    Your number: <span id="mirror1"></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    Email: 
        <input type = "text" id="userEmail" 
name="email" onkeyup="document.getElementById('mirror2').innerHTML=this.value" />
    <br />
    Your email: <span id="mirror2"></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    Gender:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gen" id="userGender" value="Decline"
checked/> Decline<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gen" id="userGender" value="Male" />Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gen" id="userGender" value="Female" /> Female

<tr>
<td>
    Major:
        <select name="major" id="userMajor">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Major</option>
        <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
        <option value="Information Technology">Information Technology</option>
        <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
        <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
    Hobbies:<br /> 
        <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Running, 
" + " " />Running<br /> 
        <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Sleeping, 
" + " "/>Sleeping<br />
    <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Fishing, 
" + " "/>Fishing<br />
    <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Other" />Other
</td>
</tr>
</table>
        <p>
        <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="Survey()"/>
    </p>
    </form>

    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Survey()
{
if (!ValidateForm())
{        
return false;
}


else {
var userName = document.forms[0].name.value+"<br />";

var userNumber = document.forms[0].number.value+"<br />";

var userEmail= document.forms[0].email.value+"<br />";

var sex;
  if (document.forms[0].gen[0].checked)
    sex=document.forms[0].gen[0].value;
  else if (document.forms[0].gen[1].checked)
    sex=document.forms[0].gen[1].value;
  else if (document.forms[0].gen[2].checked)
    sex=document.forms[0].gen[2].value;

var userGender = sex+"<br />";

var userMajor = document.forms[0].major.value+"<br />"; 

var hobby=new Array()
var counter=0;

  for (i=0;i<document.forms[0].hob.length;i++)
  {
    if (document.forms[0].hob[i].checked)
    {
        hobby[counter]=document.forms[0].hob[i].value;
        counter++;
    }

  }

var hobPick="";
for (n=0;n<hobby.length;n++)
    hobPick+=hobby[n];

var userHobby = hobPick;

document.getElementById("printName").innerHTML = userName
document.getElementById("printNumber").innerHTML = userNumber
document.getElementById("printEmail").innerHTML = userEmail
document.getElementById("printGender").innerHTML = userGender
document.getElementById("printMajor").innerHTML = userMajor
document.getElementById("printHobby").innerHTML = userHobby


document.getElementById('formtext').submit();
}
}

function ValidateForm()

{

if (document.forms[0].name.value.length === 0) 
{
alert("Name is Required");

    return false;

}

else if
(document.forms[0].number.value.length === 0) 
{
alert("Number is Required");

    return false;
}

else if
(document.forms[0].email.value.length === 0) 
{
alert("Email is Required");

    return false;
}

else if
(document.forms[0].userMajor.value === "")
{
    alert("Major is Required");

        return false;
}

else if
(document.forms[0].userHobby[0].checked === false && 
document.forms[0].userHobby[1].checked=== false &&
document.forms[0].userHobby[2].checked === false &&
document.forms[0].userHobby[3].checked === false)
{
    alert("hobby is Required");

        return false;
}
else
{   
return true;
}
}
```

PHP:

```
<table id='userInputTbl' width='600' border='1'>

<tr> 
<td id='tblName' colspan='6'> 
<strong>You Submitted: </strong><br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Name:</strong><br />
</td>
<td> <?echo $_POST["printName"]?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Number:</strong><br /></td>
<td> <?echo $_POST['printNumber']?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Email:</strong><br /></td>
<td> <?echo $_POST['printEmail']?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Gender:</strong><br /></td>
<td> <? echo $_POST['printGender']?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Major:</strong><br /></td>
<td> <? echo $_POST['printMajor']?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Hobbies:</strong><br /></td>
<td> <? echo $_POST['printHobby']?></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Please use http://codepad.org/ to add code and provide demo. Hard to understand your problem

Comment: please refer to this SO thread on how to properly use AJAXA form submission with PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this part:

```
document.getElementById("printName").innerHTML = userName
document.getElementById("printNumber").innerHTML = userNumber
document.getElementById("printEmail").innerHTML = userEmail
document.getElementById("printGender").innerHTML = userGender
document.getElementById("printMajor").innerHTML = userMajor
document.getElementById("printHobby").innerHTML = userHobby
```

No such IDs exist! by the way , ID should be unique which means only one element should have `userHobby`  as ID.

```
<td>
    Hobbies:<br /> 
        <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Running, 
" + " " />Running<br /> 
        <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Sleeping, 
" + " "/>Sleeping<br />
    <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Fishing, 
" + " "/>Fishing<br />
    <input name="hob" id="userHobby" type="checkbox" value="Other" />Other
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra `{` in your **ValidateForm()** function:

```
{
var userName = document.forms[0].name.value+"<br />";
```

Perhaps you want to change it to:

```
else {
var userName = document.forms[0].name.value+"<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your php file is broken.

```
<?php
echo <table id='userInputTbl' width='600' border='1'>
<tr> 
 <td id='tblName' colspan='6'> 
 <strong>You Submitted: </strong><br />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><strong>Name:</strong><br />
 </td>
   <td <?echo $_POST["userName"]?> ></td>
```

`echo` expects a string, but you don't need any of that anyway.

Get rid of the opening `<?php` and the echo. Go right into the html like this

```
<table id='userInputTbl' width='600' border='1'>
<tr> 
 <td id='tblName' colspan='6'> 
 <strong>You Submitted: </strong><br />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><strong>Name:</strong><br />
 </td>
   <td <?echo $_POST["userName"]?> ></td>
```

---

This part also looks wrong:

```
   <td <?echo $_POST["userName"]?> ></td>
```

I think you meant

```
   <td><?echo $_POST["userName"]?></td>
```

---

Also, in this section:

```
function Survey()
{
if (!ValidateForm())
{        
return false;
}


{
var userName = document.forms[0].name.value+"<br />";
```

The `{` is out of place. Do you mean to have an `else {` there?

---

And another thing: What is the point of displaying the values to the `id="print..."` elements if you're just submitting the form anyway? The user won't see any of it, just for a split second before they're redirected anyway. Get rid of all of that.

---

I'm back again...

You're inconsistent here:

```
document.forms[0].hob[i]
```

vs this:

```
document.forms[0].userHobby[0]
```

You should be using the names, not the ids, here. Use `hob`.

Answer (score -2):

You must do this validation in the OnSubmit event of the form, see [this article in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)